# Как правильно отрисовывать компонент Vue при его появлении

Tags: javascript, vuex, vue-cli

Есть компонент, который должен выполнять какую-то функцию какждый раз заново при появлении. Кажется для этого существуют rendrer-функции, но я не понимаю как мне это реализовать правильно во vue-cli. Или лучше использовать какой-то другой подход?

Comment: Не понятно. При появлении и так он каждый раз заново отрисовывается. Если нужно перерисовать его при изменении како-нибудь параметра, то для этого существует атрибут `:key="paramName"`, при этом, если, например, мы в условную кнопку передаём проп, который говорит, что кнопка, предположим, не активна, что-то типа `active: false`, то, скажем, при заполнении какого-нибудь инпута эту кнопку надо перерисовать и сдлеать активной, то просто биндим вэлью инпута на переменну, а переменную в качестве значения атрибута `:key` указываем для кнопки.

Comment: Про параметры окей, но надо чтобы отрисовывал при появлении чисто при помощи render-функции. Как это правильно организовать? Потому как я написал просто alert() в render и он не отработал

Comment: Извини, про рендер-функции не скажу, не пользовал. Не было нужды.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы отработала render-функция НЕ НУЖНО в компонент добавлять `<template>`, а сам рендер писать в `<script>`. Например так:

> Title.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Title',
    render: function (createElement) {
      let vueArray = [
        'Vue',
        'is',
        'awesome'
      ];
        return createElement('h1', vueArray.join(' '))
      }
  }
</script>
```